# Char cannot be dereferenced error in Bluej

Tags: compiler-errors, bluej, dereference

I am trying to write an if statement that tells what state water is in depending on the altitude and temperature. I wrote "if (unit.equals("C"))" and I keep getting the char cannot be dereferenced error. I have tried rewriting it in different ways and nothing is working.

Comment: Please note that it would be more reliable (and you'd get faster and more accurate replies !) if you provide a sample code to reproduce your error. You can refer this page about it : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

"unit" is probably not a String but a char.

In that case you might use either `if (unit == 'C')` or `if (Character.toString(unit).equals("C"))`.

Here is a nice article about this : https://www.thejavaprogrammer.com/char-cannot-be-dereferenced/